# Cygwin causing errors in Aptana when Ant builds project with HTML parsed as PHP

Tags: php, ant, cygwin, aptana

I have Aptana Studio 3, build: 3.4.0.201304151603 installed on Windows 7 (Service Pack 1).  I have configured it to associate *.html files with the PHP Source Editor by default to add code completion for (and my Apache parses *.html as) PHP.

I have a custom builder on the project to launch Ant 1.7.0 to build it.  Nothing special except to prompt for the Ant target to build.  Finally, I have Cygwin installed and mainly use it for tail'ing logs, etc.

*whew*!  Enough intro, down to the problem.

Recently, when I first fire the custom builder, the console displays the following:

```
[2013-05-09 12:24:36] #<NoMethodError: undefined method `end_node' for #<Java::ComAptanaEditorPhpInternalParserNodes::PHPHTMLNode:0xc37a88>>
ps: illegal option -- x
Usage ps [-aefl] [-u uid]
-f = show process uids, ppids
-l = show process uids, ppids, pgids, winpids
-u uid = list processes owned by uid
-a, -e = show processes of all users
-s = show process summary
-W = show windows as well as cygwin processes
```

I have yet to find any references online to the `Java::ComAptanaEditorPhpInternalParserNodes::PHPHTMLNode:0xc37a88` error (or any part thereof).  Further, I have no clue how firing an Ant build (while editing **any** file type -- HTML, CSS, JavaScript, PHP, etc.) would have anything to do with a PHP parser *or* Cygwin's `ps` command.

The error doesn't *seem* to affect anything.  everything builds, no artifacts in files, etc.  It's just uncomfortable, because it *may* be doing something I haven't found yet!!